# How can a function return the required numbers using the reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

I made a function that the user needs to input the array size, array values and it will give back the biggest and smallest number in that array.

My question is how can I return those two values by reference?

Here is my code:

```
void function()
{
    int i, n;
    int arr[10];

    cout << "Enter the size of array: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        cout << "Number " << i + 1 << " : ";
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[0] < arr[i])
            arr[0] = arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Biggest number is: " << arr[0];
    cout << endl;

    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[0] > arr[i])
            arr[0] = arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Smallest number is: " << arr[0];
}

int main()
{
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: take a look for your return value.... like in your main e.g. you can declare your function as an int function() and write at the end return arr[0];

Comment: In addition to @retinotop: The function may have _one_ return value. How to return two values (i.e. min and max)? For this, a compound type can be used, e.g. `std::pair<int, int>`.

Comment: thanks for that info that cleared things in my head, cheers

Comment: Off-topic: What happens if user enters a number > 10 or not a number at all? Recommendation: make it a good habit to *always* check user input for validity right from the start...

Comment: Store your maximum in a separate variable, not in `arr[0]`: If the minimal value is located there, you are going to lose it and find second smallest value instead.

Comment: well I didn't set up solutions for that yet but this is for practice, when I start serious project one day I will put that for sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++ it is more common to work with vectors, iterators and algorithms.
A simple solution to your problem would be:

```
std::vector<int> a1{ {1, 2, 3} };
const auto result = std::minmax_element(a1.begin(), a1.end());
auto forwardIteratorToMinimum = result.first;
auto forwardIteratorToMaximum = result.second;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like your function to return a pair of numbers you can use `std::pair` for that purpose.

```
std::pair<int, int> findMaxAndMin(int* array, int arraySize) {
    int biggest = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
    int smallest = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        if (array[i] > biggest) {
            biggest = array[i];
        }
        if (array[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = array[i];
        }
    }
    return std::make_pair(biggest, smallest);
}

int main() {
    int testArray[10] = {10, 9, 8, 7, -69, 100, -200, 300, 1, 2};
    auto result = findMaxAndMin(testArray, 10);
    std::cout << "biggest: " << result.first
        << ", smallest: " << result.second << std::endl;
}
```

However, this example is only good for learning purposes, normally we don't use C-style arrays in C++ code. To store variable length array of integers you should use `std::vector<int>`. Then, to find maximum or minimum element in the vector you should use `std::max_element` and `std::min_element`. Later, if you would like to return something more complicated then just a pair of two integers, you should define your own `struct` or `class` and write a function/method returning your custom type.

Also note that you should separate the logic responsible for calculation and logic responsible for user's input/output. I gave you only the function responsible for calculations, you can write yourself a function responsible for asking the user for the input.

Answer (score 0):

To return the results by reference You have to

1) Change the definition of the function to return references (the ampersand `&`)

From:

```
void function()
{
    // ...
}
```

To:

```
void function(int& min_value, int& max_value)
{
    // ...
}
```

2) Inside the function You have to assign values to the variables returned by reference (`min_value` and `max_value`)

3) When calling the function, variables have to be provided which will "house" the results:

From:

```
function();
```

To:

```
int min_val;
int max_val;

function(min_val, max_val);
```